# SUMIFS IN SQL QUERY

Tags: sql, db2

I need to create size categories in my SQL query from DB2 database.

[image]

I was thinking about windowed function  but I do not know how to start.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for something like this

```
select region
      ,month
      ,amount
      ,sum(amount) over (partition by region, month) as sum_amount
from tableA;
```

Comment: Bingo, that is exactly it. Thank you, :)

Comment: And what if I would like to exclude some regions? let say other than reg2 (region<>'reg2' does not work)

Comment: Can't think of a reason why `region=!'reg2'` or  what you have `region<>'reg2'`  not work. Does it give you an error?

Comment: " SQL0104N  An unexpected token "=" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "RANGE ROWS ??( [ CONCAT || / MICROSECONDS MICROSECOND SECONDS". What I did: sum(amount) over (partition by region=!'reg2', month) as sum_amount

Comment: That's not the right syntax. If you want to exclude reg2 altogether from the result set, you need to place that in the `where` clause, otherwise try `sum(case when region='reg2' then 0 else amount end) over....` You could also do `case when region='reg2' then 0 else sum(amount) over.... end`

Answer (score 0):

You can group by region and month:

```
select region,month,sum(amount) as amount
from tableA
group by region,month
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This would be the option, but sum column will be part of much bigger and more complex table.